# CentOS - /sys/class/leds/ description

Tags: linux, centos, input

How do i get informations about the files/entrys of `/sys/class/leds/`?

I have a "kana" input/led there, and wonder what it is/does.

```
[root@server ~]# ll /sys/class/leds/
insgesamt 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 28. Mär 20:12 input2::capslock -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:14DD:0002.0001/input/input2/input2::capslock
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 28. Mär 20:12 input2::compose -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:14DD:0002.0001/input/input2/input2::compose
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 28. Mär 20:12 input2::kana -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:14DD:0002.0001/input/input2/input2::kana
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 28. Mär 20:12 input2::numlock -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:14DD:0002.0001/input/input2/input2::numlock
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 28. Mär 20:12 input2::scrolllock -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:14DD:0002.0001/input/input2/input2::scrolllock
```

And why is there no "HDD" entry?
I would thought that the led flashing of the hdd led is controlled by kerenl/io calls. Should there not be a entry for that?

I found this link: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/leds/leds-class.html But there is nothing about "kana", nor in the `include/dt-bindings/leds/common.h` (https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/dt-bindings/leds/common.h) file.

Thanks for any Advice.

Answer (score 0):

The LEDs you see listed in `/sys/class/leds` seem to be all associated with the input device `input2`. You could use the `lsinput` command to identify it, but it's probably your keyboard.

The `kana` LED is a feature of keyboards built for typing e.g. Japanese. If you don't actually have a Japanese keyboard, the manufacturer may have developed an universal USB keyboard circuit board/firmware for all localized versions of their keyboards, including Japanese, and just omit the actual `kana` key and LED from keyboard layouts that won't need it.

The HDD activity LED, on the other hand, is typically directly wired to the storage controller, as its original purpose is to be a very low-level way to indicate when it is not safe to power off the system. It is not typically possible to control that LED by software (there can be exceptions for that however).